# What exactly these lines do individually and collectively in JSON parsing

Tags: android, json

I am wondering after I searched in few books and on web that none of then detailed about it. I want to know that what exactly the purpose of below line individually while we parse JSON response file :

**Lines ARE :**

```
DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Url);                  
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);   
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I know one thing that all together these four lines perform the connection with the server, but have no idea what individually the do.

I am sure I will get answer here from one of SOF besties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) Supports:

- HTTPS, streaming uploads and downloads, configurable timeouts, IPv6 and connection pooling.

[HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) :

- The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line.

[HttpResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) :

- Takes care of the response that is got after executing `client.execute(post);`

Finally the following code obtains the message entity of this response.

```
    response.getEntity()
```

Please check the android documentation for detailed implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Code above is resposible for Http post request to server and get JSON response, so that you can parse and get required data.

Answer (score 1):

Above 4 lines don't do JSON parsing. They only make an HTTP connection and the way of doing it is only recommended below Gingerbread. For Gingerbread and above use HttpURLConnection. More [details here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).

After you have the content (make a check if the response code is as expected - 200 or 201) you can proceed to JSON parsing. Use either Jackson, GSON or Android's json framework (this is my preferred order).

Comment: Okay, so these lines are now deprecated from android higher versions? and HttpURLConnection is used instead of DefaultHttpClient or in replacement of all four lines? Could you refer me an example please.

Comment: What is your question? What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: The lines are not deprecated. Just that it's recommended to use HttpURLConnection because it's a lighter class and it's better supported in Gingerbread and above. Please read the article and it will make sense. JSON parsing is another story

Comment: Actually, I am not facing any problem but recently in an interview they asked the meaning of these lines individually which I couldn't answered. So, want to know.

Comment: I know parsing is different scenario by getting the response and then fetch the OBJECT and ARRAYS. Here just wanted to know the purpose of these four only

Comment: As said in my response: they just make an http connection. But it's not that recommended to use this code in gingerbread above, even though it will work since I don't expect you're doing anything complicated on the connection. I guess a simple Http GET.

Comment: Then I am so happy you have accepted someone else's answer! :P

Comment: Actually he told me the exact answer I wanted, which is the meaning of the lines. :) Sowie

Answer (score 1):

As per may Opinion

1. **DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();** responsible for `HttpsURLConnection` efficient(Connection) when connecting to up-to-date servers, without breaking compatibility with older ones.
2. **HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Url);** responsible for get POST request and send response.
3. **HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);** responsible for executes HTTP request using the default context.
4. **HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();** responsible for carry a content entity associated with the request or response.

For more information go to:http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html